# vanishing of vector field in infinite dimensions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

A simple fact: Given a vector field on a compact manifold with boundary, if the vector field points inward along the boundary, then it must vanish somewhere in the interior. (EDIT: As pointed out in the accepted answer and in a comment, the Euler characteristic must be nonzero for this to be true.)

My question: Is there an analog of this fact in infinite dimensions? Perhaps for Banach manifolds?

Comment: I would bet against because compactness isn't available. Closed balls aren't compact.

Comment: This depends on the topology though. In general, closed balls can be compact if the model space is not Banach.

Comment: I know that the answer can't be super simple since there is no compactness, but maybe there are hypotheses that make it work. (For example, something like the Palais-Smale condition.) Even one specific situation in the literature where such an argument was used would be interesting to me.

Comment: Dan, what you claim as a "simple fact" is not true. Take for example $S^1 \times [0,1]$, this has an inward-pointing everywhere non-zero vector field.  The Poincare-Hopf index theorem is what tells you when you have to have a zero, and that's given in terms of the Euler characteristic of the manifold.

Comment: Given how embarrassingly wrong my original premise was, it's a bit awkward to ask this, but I still wonder if something interesting can be said about the unit ball in Banach space.

Comment: To answer my own question, I suppose that the Schauder fixed point theorem (being an infinite dimensional analog of the Brouwer fixed point theorem) provides some understanding of the case of the unit ball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple fact in question is false in any dimension greater than one.

Consider the strip $ \mathbb{R} \times [-\pi/2,\pi/2] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.  At a point $(x, y)$ take the vector $(-sin(y), cos(y))$.  This does not depend on $x$ so descends to a vector field on the annulus $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.  It is obviously nowhere vanishing and points inwards at the boundaries.

Comment: Thanks. The "reasoning" I had in mind was just totally bogus.